# how to implement the line in coordinates with js

Tags: javascript

i want to use javascript to implements the effect[image]

previously i use `highcharts.js`,but it have no the effect,some other framework is use point,i think is too hard to use it.
the point is dynamic,the line is drawn from the last point to the first point, what front framework can complete the assignment?
i just want to add data to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amchart is Best...](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/p9mtj44d/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
```